# Excel INDIRECT not recognizing concatenated value?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a moderate sized value matrix that collects data (60-80 values/sheet) using INDIRECT function from 50 or so sheets.

As an example:

```
=IFERROR(INDIRECT($C4&N$1);0)
```

In which:

`$C4` = concatenated value (sheet name). Reason for using the `CONCATENATE` is that value is combination of IDs for both service provider and sites. These are from data validation lists on separate sheet.

`N$1` references to cell in the sheet to retrieve value from

Problem is that the `INDIRECT`-function doesn't seem to recognize the concatenated value.

If the situation is as follows and C is concatenated value matching the sheet name the `INDIRECT` gives value 0 according to `IFERROR`.

> | A  |  B  |    C   |   |ISS | HT  | ISSHT  |
>
> A = service provider
>
> B = site name

Now if I change that ISSHT to plain text with no `CONCANATE`-formula the same `INDIRECT` formula returns the correct value from matching sheet.

Changing the cell data type in Excel has no effect to end result.

Any ideas/help to fix this is appreciated.

Comment: if you are using excel 2010 and above, try `ADDRESS()`, it can take an input where you specify the name of the sheets so it will generate the correct string for use in `indirect()`.

Comment: Your problem has nothing to do with either the `CONCATENATE` function or the concatenate operator being illegal (or even problematic) inside `INDIRECT`. The problem is that the string that you are creating with the concatenation isn't a valid reference. What is the actual string being created? For debugging purposed just have `$C4&N$1` in a cell all by itself and see.

Comment: Thanks for feedback. Feeling immensely stupid here with my currently limited Excel experience, but...  If check the INDIRECT-formula and the $C4&N$1 I gives me ISSHT! J19 as it is supposed to (matching sheet name and cell address)? If I change $C4 to plain text ISSHT the value appears the same but seems lack the space(?) after exclamation mark like this ISSHT!J19 and this works.

Comment: So I had the answer in my last comment. There was unnecessary space in the HT id in the validation list that caused the wrong value in indirect - function. Thanks for pointing to right direction!

Answer (score 0):

You can try `Address()` function to properly generate the reference in string.

[image]

Or just notice the difference from the above screenshot.

- if the sheet name contain 'space', then the name should be enclosed in `'` in the string.
- if the sheet name does not contain 'space', then the name does not have to be enclosed in `'`.

So if you don't want to use `Address()`, you need to make sure sheet name with 'space' is enclose in `'` for the reference string.

Comment: Thanks for optional solution, but it all came down to a simple typo in one the site IDs... This may come handy some other time.